# jQuery UI in bundle error every time I run the project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I downloaded the jQuery UI via nuget manager and added it in my bundleconfig and after that I encountered this error. please see below image.
[image]

BundleConfig.cs

```
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js",
                    "~Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/CustomJs/masterpage.js"
          ));
```

Comment: Missing `/` after the `~`

Comment: ahahaha! oh my heck. hoooo!!!! I need atleast 8 hours of sleep. thanks man!

Comment: You should delete the question - its just a simple typo

Comment: there's a prompt that I shouldn't delete a question , it might deprive knowledge for other/s who's not sleeping at least 8 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it like this. You are missing a / after ~ in the path.

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
```

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js",
                "~Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/CustomJs/masterpage.js"
      ));`
```

to this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/CustomJs/masterpage.js"
      ));
```

on the line "~Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js", you missed the / between ~ and Scripts

Answer (score 1):

```
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js",
            **"~Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",**   Wrong here
            "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/CustomJs/masterpage.js"
  ));
```

Change to

```
`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js",
            **"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",**   correct
            "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/CustomJs/masterpage.js"
  ));
```